# UPDATE OR JOIN QUERY?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to UPDATE or JOIN  fields **that are empty** With fields from another table

```
UPDATE b SET b.b = c.c 
WHERE 
b.b = "" 
AND 
b.x = c.x
```

However, this query is not working.

Since I try to Update Information coming from another table - do I Need a join here?

How would I do that?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: I am using MS Access

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is

```
update t2
set t2.deptid = t1.deptid
from test1 t1, test2 t2
where t2.id = t1.id
```

and your logic into that.

Comment: Maybe I should have said that I am working in MS acess. Here it is not needed to put "FROM"  
Besides that, I do not see any syntactical difference between the queries 

https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/snytax/update-query.html

Comment: That may be the logic, but that hasn't been the syntax for the last thirty years